# c# Split form code in several *.cs fies

Tags: c#, split

I have a form with many tabs.

In order to not having a huge Form1.cs file, I would like to split the methods in several Form1_1.cs, Form1_2.cs etc. file.

I do not find what is the right way to do so.
Can I repeat the same namespace and Form in several files?
Do I need to repeat all the compliler directives like "using" or only the ones that I will use in that part?

Example:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Mine
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
...
```

Any help or advice will be very welcome.

Thank you in advance.
David

Comment: You could use [UserControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx) for each tab, so you can delegate your code for each tab on separate classes.

Comment: Please refer to [#2477848](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2477848/11963) to see why splitting your form in even more partial classes might be a bad idea.

Comment: The `partial` modifier is meant for exactly this kind of situation, where you want to split a single class into multiple files.

Answer (score 7):

You already use partial class declaration. You can create several files with

```
namespace Mine
{
    public partial class Form1
```

declaration. Only the namespaces used in a particular file need to be used.
See the details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wa80x488(v=vs.120).aspx